# PHPUnit Exception testing with code coverage

Tags: php, unit-testing, exception, mocking

I have an unusual problem regarding PhpUnit/unit testing and code coverage.

## Background

Background is important in this question. The code is to be tested and 100% coverage is required as part of an audit process. I am aware of points such as "state X could never happen" or "you're not testing this usefully", or other similar points. This is a paper exercise and a project requirement.

### Current problems/items

As an example using a php function (`random_int`)which illustrates the issue:

The function `random_int($min, $max)` is a core php function.
If this is wrapped (simplified for illustatrative purposes):

```php
class Foo
{
    public function Bar(int $min, int $max)
    {
         return random_int($min, $max)
    }
}
```

*Please note that this is not the entire purpose of `Foo`.. I'm simply removing easy to test things in this example.*

This is fine. However, this throws an `\Exception` and part of the code specification is that we should return exceptions in our own namespace/Exception classes (also including suitably verbose responses etc).

So, if the class `FooException` is defined in an appropriate namespace, this can be set up as follows:

```php
class Foo
{
    public function bar(int $min, int $max)
    {
        try {
            $response =  random_int($min, $max);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new FooException('Foo::bar() threw an Exception: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This effectively ensures that it's almost (but not definitely) impossible to trigger this. (random_int throws an `\Exception` if it was not possible to gather sufficient entropy... which is unlikely)

### Mocking Attempt

In order to remedy this, it's fairly simple to create a call that simply wraps *only* the function

```php
class Foo
{
    public function bar(int $min, int $max)
    {
        try {
            $response =  $this->randomInt($min, $max);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new FooException('Foo::bar() threw an Exception: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    protected function randomInt(int $min, int $max)
    {
        return random_int($min, $max);
    }
}
```

In the unit test, these can then be mocked using a partial mock:

```php
class FooTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testRandomIntegerException()
    {
        // mock to prove an exception:
        
        $example_class_instance = $this->createPartialMock(Foo::class, ["randomInt"]);
        $expected_exception = new FooException();
        $example_class_instance
            ->expects($this->any())
            ->method("randomInt")
            ->willThrowException($expected_exception);

        // Trigger exception
        $this->expectException(GeneratorException::class);
        $example_class_instance->randomInteger(1, 5);
    }
```

This works as expected for Unit Tests, and the FooException is correctly generated.

However, this results in the code coverage not counting that test; the unit test is against a mock object, not an instance of the class.

### Using namespace overloading

It's possible to use namespace overloading:

```php
// overwrite the base functions in the same namespace as the Generator
namespace FooSpace\;

function random_int($min, $max): int
{
    throw new \Exception('Test exception');
}

namespace FooSpaceTests;

class FooTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testRandomInteger()
    {
        $foo = new Foo();

        // Trigger exception
        $this->expectException(FooException::class);
        $foo->randomInteger();
    }
}
```

This also works in terms of a test. It also ensures that the code coverage is correctly set up. However, this function overwrite is permanent as the classes are parsed. This messes other testing up, even if its in a different file/test suite.

I don't think it's possible to "unset" or "undefine" function after these tests.

## TL;DR

For a paper/requirements testing suite that should give 100% code coverage

- How do you correctly test a class method that includes core php functions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think its possible unless you compile PHP differently and/or install extensions. Would ignoring specific parts of your code in the coverage report be considered cheating in this exercise? Alternatively, you could have one test that intentionally throws an exception and one test that doesn't and would have all lines covered with your "Mocking attempt".

Comment: Hey, this is sort of what I've tested: testing a mocked object doesn't show up on coverage; it's not the tested class.

Comment: well, is your goal to have all the lines covered by ONE test? Other than that I don't really see a problem.

Comment: No. I dont think you understand. When you test a mock object it doesn't count toward code coverage, as it is not the real class. If I write 5 tests, and 1 method needs to be mocked to prove it works, sure.. Then I can all pass unit tests, but you only see the 4 tests on code coverage. Full tests and full code coverage is the aim (in as many tests as is needed).

Comment: Why can't you have one test that mocks `randomInt` with a partial mock and throws an exception and one that does not? Should that not make 100% coverage together? What part would not be covered? I see you say that the partial mock test does not count but I think you are wrong about that. Would you be able to provide a repo to demonstrate this?

Comment: No. It doesn't count it. I thought I explained this. When you create a partial mock:
Using my example:
Test 1-4 successfully tests randomInt, including code coverage.
Test 5 invokes the exception. The partial mock does NOT count towards code coverage, even if a method is not mocked. Thus the exception path is never tested wrt code coverage.